# Escape Characters in Property Filtering (Maven)

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am trying to configure the folder path using Maven property filtering to save the path in a properties file. So I have the maven property set as:

```
<home.directory>${user.home}/config/templates</home.directory>
```

In the properties file I have set it up as:

```
working.directory=${home.directory}
```

The final property file turns out like:

```
working.directory=C:\\Users\\my-laptop/config/templates
```

But when I try to do something with this property file in JAVA, I get the path as:

```
C:\\\\Users\\\\my-laptop/config/templates
```

Needless to say this path doesn't work. So I tried using `maven-resources-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <escapeWindowsPaths>false</escapeWindowsPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This one messes it up even further. I get the path as:

```
C\:Usersmy-laptop/config/templates
```

Can you please tell me a way to set this right? Like:

`C:\Users\my-laptop/config/templates` or `C:/Users/my-laptop/config/templates`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not:
    C:\Users\my-laptop/config/templates
When defining a path it's must be consistent, whether all "\" for windows of all "/" for the rest.

I'd try to change:

```
<home.directory>${user.home}/config/templates</home.directory>
```

To

```
<home.directory>${user.home}\config\templates</home.directory>
```

If you are using windows.

Comment: The thing is this application needs to be a little flexible to work both on Windows and Unix systems. So I left it with `/`. It might not look good, but at least works when I run on my local Windows machine.